# Multi-linear regression with trivial model refinement algorithms

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote this code for an assignment. It was originally meant to be written in Maple, but got very frustrated with some of Maple's idiosyncrasies that I decided to play around with Pandas instead. This is a very trivial multi-linear regression model, which calculates variable weights using least-squares optimisation, and also allows for basic forward selection and backward elimination for model refinement (both without any form of backtracking). All suggestions welcome.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import dot, mean, sqrt
from numpy.linalg import inv

def _weights(X, Y):
    # Least squares solution for the w that minimises
    #  abs(Y - dot(X,w))

    # In newer Python and Numpy, the following
    # abombination filled lines will become the much nicer:
    #  weights = (inv(X.T @ X) @ X.T) @ Y
    #  return pd.Series(weights, index=X.columns)
    abomination = inv(dot(X.T, X))
    abomination = dot(abomination, X.T)
    abomination = dot(abomination, Y)
    return pd.Series(abomination, index=X.columns)

class LinearRegression:
    '''
    (multi)linear regression model using least-squares error
    minimisation. The weights calculated for each variable are 
    available in the Series self.weights, whose labels are aligned
    to the columns of X; the constant coefficient has the label ''.

    '''
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        '''
        X: a pandas DataFrame of the independant variables
        Y: a Series of the single dependent variable

        '''
        self.X = X
        self.observed_Y = Y

        if not self.vars:
            # No indepedent vars => every Y is equal
            # (simple linear model with gradient = 0)
            intercept = mean(Y)
            self.weights = pd.Series([intercept], index=[''])
            self.fitted_Y = pd.Series(intercept, index=Y.index)
        else:
            # Augment the X with a column of 1s at the left,
            # Then the weights will come back with a
            # constant coefficient at the top.
            ones_column = pd.DataFrame({'':1}, index=X.index)
            augmented_X = ones_column.join(X)

            self.weights = _weights(augmented_X, Y)
            self.fitted_Y = augmented_X.dot(self.weights)

    @classmethod
    def empty(cls, Y):
        '''
        Create a model with the given observations for the 
        dependent variable and *no* independent variables.

        '''
        X = pd.DataFrame([], index=Y.index)
        return cls(X, Y)

    @property
    def vars(self):
        # Needs to be a list so that, eg, `if self.vars:`
        # is a test for the empty model. If this was 
        # instead a Pandas Index, that would be an error.
        return list(self.X.columns)

    def backward_elimination(self, threshold):
        '''
        Simplify the model by the method of backward
        elimination.
        Drop columns if one at a time, choosing that column
        with the least impact on the model's RMSE, but only
        if that impact is within than `threshold`.

        '''
        Y = self.observed_Y
        overall_best = self

        def impact(m):
            return abs(m.rmse - overall_best.rmse)

        while overall_best.vars:
            X = overall_best.X
            candidates = (type(self)(X.drop(i, axis=1), Y) 
                for i in overall_best.vars)
            best = min(candidates, key=impact)

            if impact(best) < threshold:
                overall_best = best
            else:
                break

        return overall_best

    def forward_selection(self, threshold):
        '''
        Improve the model by the method of forward selection.
        Starting with the empty model, progressively add one column
        at a time, choosing the one with the best improvement to RMSE
        over, but only if that improvement is at least `threshold`.

        '''
        Y = self.observed_Y

        overall_best = type(self).empty(Y)

        def improvement(m):
            return overall_best.rmse - m.rmse

        while len(overall_best.vars) < len(self.vars):
            X = overall_best.X
            candidates = (type(self)(X.join(self.X[i]), Y)
                for i in self.vars
                if i not in overall_best.vars)

            best = max(candidates, key=improvement)

            if improvement(best) >= threshold:
                overall_best = best
            else:
                break

        return overall_best

    @property
    def residuals(self):
        return self.observed_Y - self.fitted_Y

    @property
    def rmse(self):
        return sqrt(mean(self.residuals**2))

    def __str__(self):
        y = self.observed_Y.name
        intercept = "{:.3f}".format(self.weights[''])
        xs = ('{:=+7.3f}*{}'.format(self.weights[n], n)
            for n in self.vars)
        return '{} = {} {}'.format(y, intercept, ' '.join(xs))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things confuse me about `_weights`. One, why is there an underscore before the name? That's usually a convention for indicating that a variable or method are ostensibly private and shouldn't be used externally. Which brings me to my second point, why is this created as a standalone function when it's use is tied to the `LinearRegression` class? Solve both problems and put `_weights` inside `LinearRegression`.